# C++20 : Simple Softmax classifier for MNIST dataset

Tags: c++, machine-learning, c++20

I wrote a simple softmax classifier to classify MNIST digit handwriting data set. Feel free to comment anything!

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <bit>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <execution>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <memory>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

struct MNISTObject {
    std::vector<double> image;
    std::uint8_t label = -1;
    static std::uint32_t rows;
    static std::uint32_t cols;
    static std::uint8_t labels;
};

std::uint32_t MNISTObject::rows = 28;
std::uint32_t MNISTObject::cols = 28;
std::uint8_t MNISTObject::labels = 10;

constexpr std::uint32_t image_code = 2051;
constexpr std::uint32_t label_code = 2049;

void convertBigToLittleEndianIfNecessary(uint32_t& code) {
    if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::little) {
        code = ((code & 0xFF000000) >> 24) |
               ((code & 0x00FF0000) >> 8) |
               ((code & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) |
               ((code & 0x000000FF) >> 24);
    }
}

void read_uint32(std::istream& is, std::uint32_t& code) {
    if (!is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&code), sizeof code)) {
        std::cerr << "Cannot read uint32\n";
        return;
    }
    convertBigToLittleEndianIfNecessary(code);
}

void fillDataset(std::istream& images, std::istream& labels, std::vector<MNISTObject>& data_set) {
    std::uint32_t code;
    read_uint32(images, code);
    if (code != image_code) {
        std::cerr << "Wrong image code : " << code << '\n';
        return;
    }
    read_uint32(labels, code);
    if (code != label_code) {
        std::cerr << "Wrong label code : " << code << '\n';
        return;
    }

    std::uint32_t cnt_images, cnt_labels;
    read_uint32(images, cnt_images);
    read_uint32(labels, cnt_labels);
    if (cnt_images != cnt_labels) {
        std::cerr << "Image/label counts do not match\n";
        return;
    } else {
        std::cout << cnt_images << " images\n";
    }

    std::uint32_t rows, cols;

    read_uint32(images, rows);
    read_uint32(images, cols);
    if (rows != MNISTObject::rows || cols != MNISTObject::cols) {
        std::cerr << "Wrong rows and cols: " << rows << ' ' << cols << '\n';
        return;
    }
    std::cout << rows << " rows " << cols << " cols\n";

    std::uint32_t img_size = rows * cols;

    data_set.reserve(cnt_images);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < cnt_images; ++i) {
        MNISTObject obj;
        obj.image.reserve(img_size);
        std::uint8_t pixel;
        for (std::size_t p = 0; p < img_size; ++p) {
            if (!images.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&pixel), sizeof pixel)) {
                std::cerr << "Pixel read fail\n";
                return;
            }
            double pixel_val = static_cast<double>(pixel) / 255.0;
            obj.image.push_back(pixel_val);
        }
        std::uint8_t label;
        if (!labels.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&label), sizeof label)) {
            std::cerr << "Label read fail\n";
            return;
        }
        if (label >= MNISTObject::labels) {
            std::cerr << "Wrong label : " << static_cast<std::uint32_t>(label) << '\n';
            return;
        }
        obj.label = label;
        data_set.push_back(obj);
    }
    std::cout << cnt_images << " images read success\n";
}

std::pair<std::vector<MNISTObject>, std::vector<MNISTObject>> constructDataSets() {
    std::filesystem::path train_images_path = "train-images.idx3-ubyte";
    std::filesystem::path train_labels_path = "train-labels.idx1-ubyte";
    std::ifstream train_images_ifs {train_images_path, std::ios::binary};
    if (!train_images_ifs) {
        std::cerr << "Cannot open input file " << train_images_path;
    }
    std::ifstream train_labels_ifs {train_labels_path, std::ios::binary};
    if (!train_labels_ifs) {
        std::cerr << "Cannot open input file " << train_labels_path;
    }

    std::vector<MNISTObject> train_set;
    fillDataset(train_images_ifs, train_labels_ifs, train_set);

    std::filesystem::path test_images_path = "t10k-images.idx3-ubyte";
    std::filesystem::path test_labels_path = "t10k-labels.idx1-ubyte";
    std::ifstream test_images_ifs {test_images_path, std::ios::binary};
    if (!test_images_ifs) {
        std::cerr << "Cannot open input file " << test_images_path;
    }
    std::ifstream test_labels_ifs {test_labels_path, std::ios::binary};
    if (!test_labels_ifs) {
        std::cerr << "Cannot open input file " << test_labels_path;
    }

    std::vector<MNISTObject> test_set;
    fillDataset(test_images_ifs, test_labels_ifs, test_set);

    return {train_set, test_set};
}

template <typename T>
struct Matrix {
    static_assert(std::is_scalar_v<T>);
    const int R;
    const int C;
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> data;

    Matrix(int R, int C) : R {R}, C {C}, data(new T[R * C]) {
        assert(R > 0 && C > 0);
    }

    T& operator()(int r, int c) {
        assert(0 <= r && r < R && 0 <= c && c < C);
        return data[r * C + c];
    }

    const T& operator()(int r, int c) const {
        assert(0 <= r && r < R && 0 <= c && c < C);
        return data[r * C + c];
    }
};

std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());

std::vector<double> computeProb(const Matrix<double>& W, const MNISTObject& mnist_sample) {
    assert(W.R == MNISTObject::labels && W.C == MNISTObject::rows * MNISTObject::cols);
    std::vector<double> probs;
    probs.reserve(MNISTObject::labels);
    double sum_probs = 0.0;
    for (int l = 0; l < MNISTObject::labels; l++) {
        auto inner_prod = std::transform_reduce(std::execution::par_unseq,
                                                &W.data[l * W.C], &W.data[(l + 1) * W.C],
                                                mnist_sample.image.begin(), 0.0);
        auto prob = std::exp(inner_prod);
        probs.push_back(prob);
        sum_probs += prob;
    }
    std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, probs.begin(), probs.end(), [&sum_probs](auto& p){p /= sum_probs;});
    auto real_sum = std::reduce(std::execution::par_unseq, probs.begin(), probs.end(), 0.0);
    if (std::fabs(real_sum - 1.0) >= 1e-5) {
        std::cerr << "Probability sum failed in softmax: " << real_sum << '\n';
    }
    return probs;
}

constexpr int num_epochs = 100;

double testSoftmaxClassifier(const Matrix<double>& W, const std::vector<MNISTObject>& test_set) {
    int correct = 0;
    int incorrect = 0;
    for (const auto& test_sample : test_set) {
        auto probs = computeProb(W, test_sample);
        auto predict = std::distance(probs.begin(), std::ranges::max_element(probs));
        if (predict == test_sample.label) {
            correct++;
        } else {
            incorrect++;
        }
    }
    return correct / (correct + incorrect * 1.0);
}

Matrix<double> trainSoftmaxClassifier(const std::vector<MNISTObject>& train_set,
                                      const std::vector<MNISTObject>& test_set,
                                      double lr, double weight_decay) {
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> weight_dist(-1.0, 1.0);
    const int k = MNISTObject::labels;
    const int sz = MNISTObject::rows * MNISTObject::cols;
    Matrix<double> W (k, sz);
    for (int i = 0; i < k * sz; ++i) {
        W.data[i] = weight_dist(gen);
    }

    for (int epoch = 0; epoch < num_epochs; epoch++) {
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (const auto& train_sample : train_set) {
            auto probs = computeProb(W, train_sample);
            auto correct = train_sample.label;
            for (int l = 0; l < k; ++l) {
                for (int p = 0; p < sz; ++p) {
                    W(l, p) = W(l, p) * (1.0 - lr * weight_decay)
                            - lr * train_sample.image[p] * probs[l];
                }
                if (l == correct) {
                    for (int p = 0; p < sz; ++p) {
                        W(l, p) += lr * train_sample.image[p];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto dt = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1);
        std::cout << "epoch " << epoch << " finished in " << dt.count() << "ms\n";

        auto accu = testSoftmaxClassifier(W, test_set);
        std::cout << "Accuracy : " << accu << '\n';
    }

    return W;
}

int main() {
    auto [train_set, test_set] = constructDataSets();

    constexpr double lr = 0.0005;
    constexpr double weight_decay = 0;

    auto W = trainSoftmaxClassifier(train_set, test_set, lr, weight_decay);

}
```

You can download the dataset here: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

Result in my machine:

```
60000 images
28 rows 28 cols
60000 images read success
10000 images
28 rows 28 cols
10000 images read success
epoch 0 finished in 1132ms
Accuracy : 0.7536
epoch 1 finished in 1142ms
Accuracy : 0.8176
epoch 2 finished in 987ms
Accuracy : 0.8424
epoch 3 finished in 1094ms
Accuracy : 0.8574
epoch 4 finished in 1038ms
Accuracy : 0.8662
epoch 5 finished in 1191ms
Accuracy : 0.8724
epoch 6 finished in 1087ms
Accuracy : 0.8789
epoch 7 finished in 1020ms
Accuracy : 0.8838
epoch 8 finished in 1170ms
Accuracy : 0.8867
epoch 9 finished in 1150ms
Accuracy : 0.889
epoch 10 finished in 791ms
Accuracy : 0.8908
epoch 11 finished in 815ms
Accuracy : 0.8919
epoch 12 finished in 809ms
Accuracy : 0.8929
epoch 13 finished in 792ms
Accuracy : 0.8934
epoch 14 finished in 798ms
Accuracy : 0.894
epoch 15 finished in 816ms
Accuracy : 0.8959
epoch 16 finished in 826ms
Accuracy : 0.8965
epoch 17 finished in 990ms
Accuracy : 0.8978
epoch 18 finished in 804ms
Accuracy : 0.8983
epoch 19 finished in 907ms
Accuracy : 0.8995
epoch 20 finished in 800ms
Accuracy : 0.9002
...
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In addition to Toby Speight's remarks, I would add:

## Use `constexpr` for all constants

I see you already used `constexpr` for `image_code` and `label_code`, but you didn't use it for the `static` member variables `rows`, `cols` and `labels` of `MNISTObject`. But those look like they are constants as well. You can just write:

```
struct MNISTObject {
    ...
    static constexpr std::uint32_t rows = 28;
    static constexpr std::uint32_t cols = 28;
    static constexpr std::uint8_t labels = 10;
};
```

## Make variables and functions `static` where appropriate

Variables and functions that are only used within the same [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) should be made `static`. This might help the compiler produce more efficient code, and avoids potential symbol collision at link time.

## Prefer `return`ing values from functions

I see a lot of functions that return `void`, but write their result via a parameter passed by reference. I would avoid this pattern and instead use `return` to return the result. First, passing in a reference is less efficient if the compiler cannot inline the function. But more importantly, it just makes it harder to write code. Consider:

```
std::uint32_t code;
read_uint32(images, code);
if (code != image_code) {...}
```

If you instead let `read_uint32()` `return` the value it read, you can write the above snippet of code as:

```
if (read_uint32(images) != image_code) {...}
```

Another benefit is that it will now force you to `return` something, even if an error occured. Because in this code:

```
std::uint32_t code;
read_uint32(images, code);
```

The value of `code` is left uninitialized if there is a read error, but your program continues to go on. There is a tiny chance that the value 2051 would have been in the memory reserved for `code`, so your program might incorrectly go on assuming the right image code was read. I would follow Toby's advice here and `throw` an exception (preferably a [`std::runtime_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) or something derived from it):

```
uint32_t read_uint32(std::istream& is) {
    if (uint32_t code; is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&code), sizeof code)) {
        return convertBigToLittleEndianIfNecessary(code);
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("Read error");
    }
}
```

Also note that you should also `return` for large objects, which is still as efficient as passing it via a reference parameter thanks to [return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization). So `fillDataSet` should just `return` the dataset (and have its name changed to `readDataSet()` to reflect that).

## Optimize reading from files

You are reading the image data from the input file byte by byte. This is quite inefficient. I suggest you read the whole image in one go instead:

```
auto pixels = std::make_unique_for_ovewrite<std::uint8_t[]>(img_size);
if (!images.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(pixels.get()), img_size)) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Read error");
}

std::transform(pixels.get(), pixels.get() + img_size, std::back_inserter(obj.image),
               [](std::uint8_t pixel){ return pixel / 255.0; });
```

Comment: Upvoted. Isn't ```make_unique``` more preferable than ```make_unique_for_overwrite```? There will be unnecessary zero-fill cost.

Comment: `std::make_unique_for_overwrite` is the one that avoids "zero-fill cost" if possible; it uses [default-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) for the storage, whereas `std::make_unique` uses [value-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). The name is also a hint: it should be used when you are going to overwrite the values anyway, and that's exactly what we're doing when reading the image data into `pixels`.

Comment: I personally think that anonymous namespaces look somewhat nicer than static functions, but functionally they are the same.

Comment: You are worried about the overhead of zero-initialising a memory block when reading a file? Lol. Any gains resulting from would be impossible to measure because they are swamped by the time taken to read the file.

Comment: @Sjoerd A `std::istream` doesn't have to be a file, and even if it is, the file might already be cached in memory.

Answer (score 10):

That's a very big list of includes!  It might be a sign that you have functionality that should be split out to separate source files (e.g. filesystem read/write away from the core computation).  Keeping the standard library includes alphabetical is a good choice - it allows very easy checking of whether a needed header is already included.

This looks broken, and suggests you're lacking a good unit test:

> ```
> void convertBigToLittleEndianIfNecessary(uint32_t& code) {
>     if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::little) {
>         code = ((code & 0xFF000000) >> 24) |
>                ((code & 0x00FF0000) >> 8) |
>                ((code & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) |
>                ((code & 0x000000FF) >> 24);
>     }
> }
> ```

The last subexpression will always be zero - I think that the last two subexpressions should have `<<` where you've written `>>`.

The error reporting is poor - a lot of `void`-returning functions print user warnings to `std::cerr` (good) but have no way to signal to their callers that they will be working with invalid data (bad).  It would be more useful to `throw` an exception than to simply `return`.  (Again, more unit-testing would be good - I usually start new code by creating a test with invalid input as my very first step.)

A couple of minor niggles with the matrix class:

- Is there a good reason to use (signed) `int` for the dimensions?
- I'd prefer to see `std::make_unique<T[]>(R*C)` than the bare `new`.
- I don't see why it would only work for scalar `T`.  It's generally better to constrain using Concepts where possible (e.g. `template<std::semiregular T> struct Matrix`).

I would write `correct++`, `incorrect++` and `epoch++` using prefix operator, as that's a good general habit (use postfix operator only when we actually need the original value).  The code is inconsistent, since we have `++i` and `++p` elsewhere.

Comment: Good catch for endian conversion, thanks! I always prefer signed integers for dimensions, because it helps to catch naughty constructs like ```Matrix<double> M(-1, -1)```. I agree all the other things you've pointed out.

Comment: Good compiler warnings (`-Wconversion` for GCC, I think) will alert you to such misuses, unless you accept signed values.  I prefer to be notified at compile time than at run time (and I use `-Werror` to ensure the issues are addressed).  It also reduces the number of unit tests to write and maintain.

Answer (score 8):

Toby Speight and G. Sliepen gave excellent feedbacks from the programmer's perspective;

A friend of mine gave some feedbacks from the machine learning researcher's perspective, as follows:

- User should be able to specify hyperparameters (lr, weight_decay, etc), or the code should include hyperparameter tuning
- Weight matrix initialization is wrong. It should use a Gaussian distribution with mean 0, stdev `sqrt(2/(#fanin + #fanout))`
- Training should stop early if converged enough.
- This softmax implementation is vulnerable to overflow/underflow. Use logsumexp trick instead.
- It'd be good to include an option to specify batch size and work with it
- `double` is overkill for such simple jobs like MNIST: use float32 instead

**UPDATE**: Addressed most of feedbacks.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <bit>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <concepts>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <execution>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <memory>
#include <random>
#include <queue>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct MNISTObject {
    std::vector<float> image;
    std::uint8_t label = -1;
    static constexpr std::uint32_t rows = 28;
    static constexpr std::uint32_t cols = 28;
    static constexpr std::uint8_t labels = 10;
};

constexpr std::uint32_t image_code = 2051;
constexpr std::uint32_t label_code = 2049;

std::uint32_t convertBigToLittleEndianIfNecessary(std::uint32_t code) {
    if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::little) {
        code = ((code & 0xFF000000) >> 24) |
               ((code & 0x00FF0000) >> 8) |
               ((code & 0x0000FF00) << 8) |
               ((code & 0x000000FF) << 24);
    }
    return code;
}

std::uint32_t read_uint32(std::istream& is) {
    if (std::uint32_t code; is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&code), sizeof code)) {
        return convertBigToLittleEndianIfNecessary(code);
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't read uint32\n");
    }
}

std::vector<MNISTObject> readDataset(std::istream& images, std::istream& labels) {
    auto code = read_uint32(images);
    if (code != image_code) {
        std::cerr << code << " : ";
        throw std::runtime_error("Wrong image code\n");
    }
    code = read_uint32(labels);
    if (code != label_code) {
        std::cerr << code << " : ";
        throw std::runtime_error("Wrong label code\n");
    }

    auto cnt_images = read_uint32(images);
    auto cnt_labels = read_uint32(labels);
    if (cnt_images != cnt_labels) {
        std::cerr << cnt_images << ' ' << cnt_labels << " : ";
        throw std::runtime_error("Image/label counts do not match\n");
    } else {
        std::cout << cnt_images << " images\n";
    }

    auto rows = read_uint32(images);
    auto cols = read_uint32(images);
    if (rows != MNISTObject::rows || cols != MNISTObject::cols) {
        std::cerr << rows << ' ' << cols << " : ";
        throw std::runtime_error("Wrong rows and cols\n");
    }
    std::cout << rows << " rows " << cols << " cols\n";

    std::uint32_t img_size = rows * cols;

    std::vector<MNISTObject> data_set;
    data_set.reserve(cnt_images);
    auto pixels = std::make_unique<std::uint8_t[]>(img_size);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < cnt_images; ++i) {
        MNISTObject obj;
        obj.image.reserve(img_size);
        if (!images.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(pixels.get()), img_size)) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Image read error\n");
        }

        std::transform(pixels.get(), pixels.get() + img_size, std::back_inserter(obj.image),
                       [](std::uint8_t pixel){ return static_cast<float>(pixel) / 255.0f; });
        std::uint8_t label = 0;
        if (!labels.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&label), sizeof label)) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Label read error\n");
        }
        if (label >= MNISTObject::labels) {
            std::cerr << static_cast<std::uint32_t>(label) << " : ";
            throw std::runtime_error("Wrong label\n");
        }
        obj.label = label;
        data_set.push_back(obj);
    }
    std::cout << cnt_images << " images read success\n";
    return data_set;
}

std::pair<std::vector<MNISTObject>, std::vector<MNISTObject>> constructDataSets() {
    std::filesystem::path train_images_path = "train-images.idx3-ubyte";
    std::filesystem::path train_labels_path = "train-labels.idx1-ubyte";
    std::ifstream train_images_ifs {train_images_path, std::ios::binary};
    if (!train_images_ifs) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Cannot open train images file\n");
    }
    std::ifstream train_labels_ifs {train_labels_path, std::ios::binary};
    if (!train_labels_ifs) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Cannot open train labels file\n");
    }

    auto train_set = readDataset(train_images_ifs, train_labels_ifs);

    std::filesystem::path test_images_path = "t10k-images.idx3-ubyte";
    std::filesystem::path test_labels_path = "t10k-labels.idx1-ubyte";
    std::ifstream test_images_ifs {test_images_path, std::ios::binary};
    if (!test_images_ifs) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Cannot open test images file\n");
    }
    std::ifstream test_labels_ifs {test_labels_path, std::ios::binary};
    if (!test_labels_ifs) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Cannot open test labels file\n");
    }

    auto test_set = readDataset(test_images_ifs, test_labels_ifs);

    return {train_set, test_set};
}

template <std::regular T>
struct Matrix {
    const int R;
    const int C;
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> data;

    Matrix(int R, int C) : R {R}, C {C}, data(std::make_unique<T[]>(R * C)) {
        assert(R > 0 && C > 0);
    }

    T& operator()(int r, int c) {
        assert(0 <= r && r < R && 0 <= c && c < C);
        return data[r * C + c];
    }

    const T& operator()(int r, int c) const {
        assert(0 <= r && r < R && 0 <= c && c < C);
        return data[r * C + c];
    }
};

std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());

std::vector<float> computeProb(const Matrix<float>& W, const MNISTObject& mnist_sample) {
    assert(W.R == MNISTObject::labels && W.C == MNISTObject::rows * MNISTObject::cols);
    std::vector<float> probs;
    probs.reserve(MNISTObject::labels);
    for (int l = 0; l < MNISTObject::labels; l++) {
        auto prob = std::transform_reduce(std::execution::par_unseq,
                                                &W.data[l * W.C], &W.data[(l + 1) * W.C],
                                                mnist_sample.image.begin(), 0.0f);
        probs.push_back(prob);
    }
    auto max_prob = *std::ranges::max_element(probs);
    std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, probs.begin(), probs.end(), [&max_prob](auto& p){p = std::exp(p - max_prob);});
    auto sum_probs = std::reduce(std::execution::par_unseq, probs.begin(), probs.end(), 0.0f);
    std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, probs.begin(), probs.end(), [&sum_probs](auto& p){p /= sum_probs;});
    return probs;
}

float testSoftmaxClassifier(const Matrix<float>& W, const std::vector<MNISTObject>& test_set) {
    int correct = 0;
    int incorrect = 0;
    for (const auto& test_sample : test_set) {
        auto probs = computeProb(W, test_sample);
        auto predict = std::distance(probs.begin(), std::ranges::max_element(probs));
        if (predict == test_sample.label) {
            correct++;
        } else {
            incorrect++;
        }
    }
    return static_cast<float>(correct) / static_cast<float>(correct + incorrect);
}

constexpr int num_epochs = 300;

Matrix<float> trainSoftmaxClassifier(const std::vector<MNISTObject>& train_set,
                                      const std::vector<MNISTObject>& test_set,
                                      float lr, float weight_decay) {
    const int k = MNISTObject::labels;
    const int sz = MNISTObject::rows * MNISTObject::cols;
    std::normal_distribution<float> weight_dist(0, std::sqrt(2.0f / (k + sz * 1.0f)));
    Matrix<float> W (k, sz);
    for (int i = 0; i < k * sz; ++i) {
        W.data[i] = weight_dist(gen);
    }

    std::deque<float> prev_accu;
    constexpr int accu_window_size = 5;

    for (int epoch = 0; epoch < num_epochs; epoch++) {
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (const auto& train_sample : train_set) {
            auto probs = computeProb(W, train_sample);
            auto correct = train_sample.label;
            for (int l = 0; l < k; ++l) {
                for (int p = 0; p < sz; ++p) {
                    W(l, p) = W(l, p) * (1.0f - lr * weight_decay)
                              - lr * train_sample.image[p] * probs[l];
                }
                if (l == correct) {
                    for (int p = 0; p < sz; ++p) {
                        W(l, p) += lr * train_sample.image[p];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto dt = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1);
        std::cout << "epoch " << epoch << " finished in " << dt.count() << "ms\n";

        auto accu = testSoftmaxClassifier(W, test_set);
        std::cout << "Accuracy : " << accu << '\n';

        prev_accu.push_back(accu);
        if (prev_accu.size() > accu_window_size) {
            prev_accu.pop_front();
        }
        if (prev_accu.size() == accu_window_size &&
        *std::ranges::max_element(prev_accu) - *std::ranges::min_element(prev_accu) < 3e-4) {
            std::cout << "Converged enough, stopping the training\n";
            break;
        }
    }

    return W;
}

int main() {
    auto [train_set, test_set] = constructDataSets();

    constexpr float lr = 0.0005;
    constexpr float weight_decay = 0;

    auto W = trainSoftmaxClassifier(train_set, test_set, lr, weight_decay);

}
```

Result:

```
60000 images
28 rows 28 cols
60000 images read success
10000 images
28 rows 28 cols
10000 images read success
epoch 0 finished in 774ms
Accuracy : 0.8874
epoch 1 finished in 743ms
Accuracy : 0.9004
epoch 2 finished in 847ms
Accuracy : 0.9045
epoch 3 finished in 872ms
Accuracy : 0.9083
epoch 4 finished in 871ms
Accuracy : 0.9109
epoch 5 finished in 849ms
Accuracy : 0.9124
...
epoch 45 finished in 629ms
Accuracy : 0.9226
epoch 46 finished in 606ms
Accuracy : 0.9227
Converged enough, stopping the training
```

Better than before! Machine learning is fun.

Comment: Thanks for adding this self-answer.  It fills in aspects I'm not qualified to comment on and may be educational if I ever have to venture into this territory.

Answer (score 5):

## function should return values

Others have mentioned "return things rather than using output parameters" but here is an elaborated example.

```
void read_uint32(std::istream& is, std::uint32_t& code)
```

In this case, it's providing a primitive type so you don't even have the idea of avoiding large return values, so what's up with that?  It's not returning an error code to indicate an *optional* result either, so why would you not just naturally write it as

```
std::uint32_t read_uint32(std::istream& is)
```

?

Look at how you need to call it:

```
std::uint32_t cnt_images, cnt_labels;
read_uint32(images, cnt_images);
read_uint32(labels, cnt_labels);

std::uint32_t rows, cols;
read_uint32(images, rows);
read_uint32(images, cols);
```

You should *initialize variables when defining them* and this out-parameter thing gets in the way of that.  Having proper initialization also means that you can make them `const`:

```
const auto rows = read_uint32(images);
const auto cols = read_uint32(images);
```

## includes?

Your long list of `#include` directives has some things I don't see being used, and in fact I find are rarely needed, like `<iterator>`.  Did you paste in a long commonly needed list when you started your file, instead of just naming what you actually needed?
I'll usually comment on the `#include` line why I need it, if it's a specific feature that's not pervasive in the file.